# Why is there no 32bit Windows installer for PostgreSQL 11.1?

Tags: postgresql, windows-installer, postgresql-11

Is this just temporary? Still work in progress?
(80% of our clients still use Win7pro32bit.)

Comment: This seems more like a question for the vendor than for this community.

Comment: @David Sadly no info on vendor page about this. Searched 6 hours long, including forums.

Comment: Did your search include reaching out to them and *asking*?  The use of the word "clients" implies some sort of business, and it's a good idea for businesses to maintain some kind of support relationship with the vendors of their business-critical products.

Comment: I'd assume that it's simply a lack of demand. There are very few reasons to be running a 32-bit OS in this day and age, and even fewer on an actively-maintained production database server. As David suggested, I'd just ask the vendor if they're working on a 32-bit installer. If not... Well, they are in the PostgreSQL support business, so I'm sure they'd build you one, for the right price...

Comment: I can somewhat understand still running Windows 7, but why would anyone run a 32bit version of that - especially on a database server. Not even smartphones run 32bit software nowadays. But you could check if the installer from 2ndQuadrant supports 32bit: https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/resources/postgresql-installer-2ndquadrant/ The binaries from BigSQL are also only 64bit. You probably need [to compile them yourself](https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/compiling-postgresql-extensions-visual-studio-windows/)

Comment: Is it just the installer being 64-bit? It can still install 32-bit binaries by means of a 64-bit setup. Surely the hardware they run on is not 32-bit? That would be vintage indeed. They just prefer 32-bit for speed issues or some other technicality? [**PostgreSQL Support**](https://www.postgresql.org/support/). If the setup is wrapped as an MSI you can extract files using an [**Administrative installation**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5751980/129130) (glorified msiexec.exe file extraction mechanism). Add `platform column` to Task Manager to see what the binary is. There are other ways too.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you for the link! :) Please repeat it as an **answer** so I can accept.

Comment: Since multiple comments asked: there are several reasons to run 32bit OS in restaurant enviroment:  **1.** Stability of POS device drivers!!! **2.** Less memory usage of 32bit programs (default integer allocation only 4bytes, etc.) **3.** Cheap 1GB Win-Tablets have sometimes 32bit preinstalled. **4.** 32 bit program run faster on a 32bit OS than in a "WOW64 sandbox". **5.** Easier support. **6.** .... and many many more reasons.

Comment: Hi, were you able to find a 32-bit installer from Postgres 11?

Comment: @Error Sadly not. That [link](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/resources/postgresql-installer-2ndquadrant/) a_horse.. wrote about is for Win8+ only, so I can not even test, if it's installing on a 32bit or not.

Comment: @SzakiLaci any new about the 32bit version coming ? doesn't matter Installer or zip files