# iisnode msi file doesn't install in preferred location

Tags: windows, windows-installer, iisnode

I have msi file for iisnode, my machine is winx64. I want to install iisnode in preferred location. When I run the msi file it is installed, by default at C:\programFiles

I want to install in different location, because, TFS server will be deploying and replacing artifact inside the iisnode\www. It is not good idea to have replacing contents inside C:programFiles.

I tried msiexec.exe /a yarn-1.10.1.msi TARGETDIR=C:\cygwin64\home but didn't succeed,I have in the pic below [image: click for image](installation package cannot be opened)

If anyone have suceeded in installing msi file in different location when customization doesn't exist will be great, thank you

Comment: Not familiar with this, maybe see if an [administrative installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564619/what-is-the-purpose-of-administrative-installation-initiated-using-msiexec-a/5751980#5751980) will extract the files and see if you can just put them in a folder where you need them. There might be operations that need to be done on the files such as registering services and such, but I don't know. Inspecting the MSI would reveal this. Where can this MSI be found?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'm not sure why your screenshot specifies an /a switch for an administrative installation?  You want to use /i instead for a normal installation.

Use this command line (/qb for a 'basic' user interface, or change to /qn for a silent installation):

```
msiexec /i yarn-1.10.1.msi INSTALLDIR=c:\cygwin64\home /qb
```

Comment: Not sure that is an msi at all?

Comment: Yes, it is.  See here for the download location: [Yarn 1.10.1](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/releases/tag/v1.10.1)

Comment: Thanks, guess I didn't do my "due diligence" there :-). Will have a look-see.

Comment: No probs @stein-Åsmul.  I imagine the title of the question probably needs changing to "Yarn msi file doesn't install in preferred location" instead. ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if you are trying to install the app or creating administrative installation?
but the above mentioned error suggests that the yarn-1.10.1.msi is not available in C:\iisnode1 folder. Could you please check that once.

Comment: This isn't an answer @Vivek - it's a comment.

Comment: @Captain_Planet I had tried the Yarn msi and above mentioned command worked fine. Above error replicates when msi is not present at the specified location. So, i thought it as an answer.