# MySQL Workbench no install zip download link

Tags: mysql, zip, windows-installer

I'm looking for the zip file containing mysql workbench to install it without an msi installer but I couldn't find it. I checked mysql official website but only found the msi installer there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/ - using [an administrative installation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5751980/129130) you can extract files from an MSI. Essentially: `msiexec.exe /a MySetup.msi` in a cmd.exe prompt.

Comment: This MSI has some mechanisms to prevent administrative installation. This might have to do with a known WiX GUI problem. Here is a workaround you can try: `msiexec /a mysql-installer-community-8.0.23.0.msi TARGETDIR="D:\MyExtractionFolder"` - replace the TARGETDIR path with your own desired extraction folder. Run from a cmd.exe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/workbench/en/news-6-3-9.html (2017-02-07) says:

> Windows: Zip packages and 32-bit binaries are no longer published. The .NET Framework version 4.5 is now required.

I browsed the downloads for MySQL Workbench versions 6.3.9 and later, and I didn't see any that publish a zip archive. So it seems that policy referenced in the release notes is still true.

So your options are:

- Download the MSI installer.
- Download the zip archive for version 6.3.8, but remain at that version forever.
- Download the source and build it yourself with Visual Studio 2017 (instructions are in the [INSTALL file](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/8.0/INSTALL)).

Comment: Nice summary. I added a comment on extracting the MSI using administrative installation. Perhaps that helps too. I discovered an extraction bug and added a workaround in my comment above.

Comment: Just tried out 6.3.8. It works on Windows 10 but not 11. So those reading this answer in 2025 should be aware that option is a no-go.