# Speed up Build-Process of WiX-Installer

Tags: visual-studio, wix, windows-installer, installation, heat

For my Wix project I am harvesting 4 directories, via the pre-build-event of visual studio, which will result in about 160mb of data, and about 220 files, but the build process tooks very long.

How can i speed that process up? I have one embedded **media.cab** file which will hold all the files. Is it the size or the amount of files that will slow the process down? Or is it the harvesting with the heat tool in the pre-build-event? Would it be faster with the HeatDirectory element?

Anyone made some experience with speeding this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***WiX Help File***: [**How To: Optimize build speed**](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/general/optimizing_builds.html). In other words: **`1)`** **`Cabinet reuse`** and **`2)`** **`multi-threaded cab creation`** are built-in mechanisms in WiX to speed up builds.

---

***Hardware***: The inevitable **`"throw hardware at it"`**. New **`SSD`** and **`NVMe`** disks are so much faster than older IDE drives that you might want to try them as another way to improve build speed and installation speed. Obvious yes, but very important. It can really improve the speed of development. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66723368/129130).

***Challenges with NVMe drives?***: **`1)`** They run hot, **`2)`** they usually have limited capacity (size), **`3)`** they might be more vulnerable than older 2.5" drives when used in laptops (I am not sure - keep in mind that some NVMe drives are soldered solid to the motherboard on laptops), **`4)`** data rescue can be a bit challenging if you don't have good quality external enclosures (form factor etc...), **`5)`** NVMe drives are said to burn out over time, **`6)`** They are still somewhat pricey - especially the larger capacity ones, and there are further challenges for sure - **but overall: these drives are awesome**.

---

***Compression***: You can try to compile your setup with a different [**compression level**](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/media.html) (for example **[none](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/simple_type_compressionleveltype.html)** for **debug builds**). No compression makes builds faster. Here are illustrations for doing the opposite, setting higher compression (just use none instead of high for your purpose):

- **`CompressionLevel`**: [Msi two times larger than msm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25688101/msi-two-times-larger-than-msm/25703144#25703144)
- **`MediaTemplate`**: [How can I reduce the size of a 1GB MSI file using Orca?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56380485/how-can-i-reduce-the-size-of-a-1gb-msi-file-using-orca/56380980#56380980)

A related answer on compression: [What is the compression method used by MSI files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208195/what-is-the-compression-method-used-by-msi-files/6313772#6313772)

***Separate Setup***: If you still go compressed, you could put **prerequisites** and **merge modules** in a **separate setup** to avoid compressing them for every build (or use release flags if you are in Installshield, or check the [Preprocessor](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/preprocessor.html) features in Wix).

***External Source Files***: I suppose you could use **external source files** if that's acceptable - then you don't have a lengthy compression operation taking place during the build, just a file copy (which keeps getting faster - especially with flash drives).

***Shim***: Another technique is to **shim** all the files you install to be **1 KB** if what you are testing is the setup itself and its GUI and custom actions. It is then just a "shell" of a setup - which is a great way to test new custom actions to your setup. Many have written tools for this, but I don't have a link for you. There is always [github.com](http://github.com) to search.

***Release Flags***: Another way to save time is to use special **release flags** (Installshield only) to compile smaller versions of the setup you are working on at the moment (leaving out many features). WiX has similar possibilities via its [preprocessor](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/preprocessor.html). More on [WiX preprocessor practical use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49449985/wix-installer-setting-component-condition-property-when-doing-a-msiexec-admin/49501700#49501700).

---

***Debug Build***: I usually use combinations of these techniques to make a **debug build**.

- I normally use external source files when I experiment and add new features and keep rebuilding and installing the setup all the time.
- Release flags to compile only part of the setup, cabinet reuse and release flags combined can save a lot of time depending on the size of your setup, the number of files and your hardware configuration.
- Perhaps the most effective is a separate setup in my opinion (provided it is stable and not changing that often). Beware though: [Wix to Install multiple Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542656/wix-to-install-multiple-applications/1546916#1546916) (the problems involved when it comes to splitting setups).

***My take on it***: go for a **prerequisites-only separate setup**. This is good also for **Large Scale Deployment scenarios** where corporate users want to use their own, standardized prerequisites and are annoyed with lots of embedded "junk" in a huge setup. A lot of package preparation time in large companies is spent taking out outdated runtimes and prerequisites. You can also deliver updates to these prerequisites without rebuilding your entire setup. Good de-coupling.

---

***Links:***

- [How can I speed up MSI package install and uninstall?](https://serverfault.com/questions/594660/how-can-i-speed-up-msi-package-install-and-uninstall)

Comment: actually the compression level pretty much saved me the half of the build time, but also now i have about 450mb instead of 160mb. What do you exactly mean with "external source file"?

Comment: **External source files** means the files are put in a folder hierarchy next to the compiled MSI and they are not embedded in a cab at all. This form of build is most commonly used for installation DVDs or CD-ROMs since it makes the install faster without the decompression requirements and there is no need to make a single file for easy download. The source folder looks similar to an admin install of your MSI (which extracts all cab files and makes a network installation point). See details here: [admin install](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547809/extract-msi-from-exe/24987512#24987512)

Comment: Curious, did you set none for compression level? How does low perfom?

Comment: Yes i've set it to none and then i got the 450mb file, but also about the half of the building time

Answer (score 9):

For us, the vast majority of the time was spent invoking `light` (for the linking phase).

`light` is very slow at compressing cabinets. Changing the `DefaultCompressionLevel` in the .wixproj from `high` to `mszip` (or `low` or `none`) helps a lot. However, our build was still too slow.

It turns out that `light` handles cabinets independently, and automatically links them on multiple threads by default. To take advantage of this parallelism, you need to generate multiple cabinets. In our .wxs `Product` element, we had the following that placed everything in a single cabinet:

```
<MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />
```

It turns out you can use the `MaximumUncompressedMediaSize` attribute to declare the threshold (in MB) at which you want files to be automatically sharded into different .cab files:

```
<MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" MaximumUncompressedMediaSize="2" />
```

Now `light` was much faster, even with `high` compression, but still not fast enough for incremental builds (where only a few files change).

Back in the .wixproj, we can use the following to set up a cabinet cache, which is ideal for incremental builds where few files change and most cabinets don't need to be regenerated:

```
<CabinetCachePath>$(OutputPath)cabcache\</CabinetCachePath>
<ReuseCabinetCache>True</ReuseCabinetCache>
```

Suppressing validation also gives a nice speedup (light.exe spends about a third of its time validating the .msi by default). We activate this for debug builds:

```
<SuppressValidation>True</SuppressValidation>
```

With these changes, our final (incremental) build went from over a minute to a few seconds for a 32 MB .msi output, and a full rebuild stayed well under a minute, even with the `high` compression level.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, don't harvest files.  Please see my blog article: [Dealing with very large number of files](http://blog.iswix.com/2007/06/dealing-with-very-large-number-of-files.html)

> The third downside is that your build will take A LOT longer to
>   perform since it's not only creating your package but that it's also
>   authoring and validating your component definitions.

I maintain an open source project on CodePlex called [IsWiX](http://iswix.codeplex.com/). It contains project templates (scaffolding) and graphical designers to assist you in setting up and maintaining your WiX source.   That said, it was designed around merge modules which slows the build down a bit as the .MSM has to be built and then merged into the .MSI.   Pure fragments would be faster if you are really concerned about pure speed.  That said I have many installers around 160mb and it doesn't take long at all.

And of course don't forget about having a fast build machine.  CPU, RAM and SSD disk I/O all contribute to fast generation of MSIs. For my consulting, I use Microsoft Visual Studio Online (VSO).  I have a Core i7-2600k Hyper-V server with 32GB of ram and a Samsung 850evo SSD. My build server (VM) runs a TFS proxy server for local SCC caching.

For fun, on the above machine, I took a 220 files from my system32 folder totaling 160MB.  It took 30 seconds to build the MSM and 30 seconds to build the MSI for a total of 60 seconds.   This is 'fast enough' for me.  I would expect an MSI authored using only fragments to take 30 seconds.

Comment: I actually measured the speed now. With heat tool i got 102 seconds, with heat disabled and just took the generated files it was about 101 seconds, so the generation of the files isn't the problem. So is it the pre-processor-variables or really the amount of data? My Pc is not that slow and i'm on a I7-3770 @ 3.4GHz

Comment: Virus scanner?  You'd have to share your content with me for me to look deeper.  Heat might not be slower in your situation but I've seen it.  Especially when you start getting COM harvesting involved.