# ISDEV : fatal error -7108: %s is too large to store in a .cab (2 GB maximum)

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

Our product is using Basic MSI to create setup.exe (IS 2016).

We do have lot of files and hence we have the following settings in settings.xml file to create multiple cab files if it exceeds certain limit.

```
CompressedNetworkCABSize default="600"
```

Since the file size is more already it is creating around 2 cab files.

Recently the setup fails with the following error

ISDEV : fatal error -7108: %s is too large to store in a .cab (2 GB maximum)

The size of the data2.cab file exceeds 2 GB and hence we got this error. But why it is not creating a new cab file?

Comment: https://community.flexera.com/t5/InstallShield-Forum/ISDEV-fatal-error-7108-s-is-too-large-to-store-in-a-cab-2-GB/m-p/183032. Is it possible for your product to put some material online instead of installing locally? It tends to work well for training material, help files and such things: [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53905088/129130)

Comment: Hi Stein, yeah the work is in progress. We do have a project where we move all the help file contents from installing locally to a cloud location. That will definitely reduce bunch of file contents and size.

Comment: I would check with that Installshield community if newer versions of Installshield has better support for bigger files. Keep in mind that the FAT32 file system only supports files up to 4GB. You can get some unfortunate problems with your installers if they are larger than that (user complaints and problems - obviously).

Comment: On a slightly different note: [how to speed up the build process of a setup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30033958/129130). Not quite related, but with 2GB cabs the build might take a while - InstallShield should have something for cabinet reuse I think.