# Wix: How can I create a bundle.exe with more than 2GB (external files)

Tags: cmake, wix, cpack

I have multiple MSI files and I am creating bundle .exe using WIX. The bundle started to exceed 2GB. From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55317746/5619109) I understand it cannot be done within a single .exe file because burn does not support containers bigger than 2GB.

Is it possible to produce .exe installer with (e.g. external .cab files)?
The .exe file would have less than 2GB, but it would require external files?

Comment: Just a couple of links: [the online and / or compression workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56380980/129130),  and [a similar answer thrown in](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53905088/129130). I don't think there are fixes in the latest development releases, but [here they are - latest, public WiX developmental releases](https://wixtoolset.org/releases/development/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Bundle Name="Bundle Name" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Company Inc." UpgradeCode="YOUR_GUID_HERE">
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense" />

    <Chain>
      <MsiPackage SourceFile="stage\msi1.msi" Vital="yes" Visible="yes"/>
      <MsiPackage SourceFile="stage\msi2.msi" Vital="yes" Visible="yes"/>
      <!-- etc... -->
      <!-- msi which will not be compressed: -->
      <MsiPackage DownloadUrl="{0}" SourceFile="stage\external.msi" Vital="yes" Visible="yes"  Compressed="no"/>
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

This results in a chain of msi1, msi2 files (included in .exe).
External.msi file is not included in the bundle, thus it is required to be placed next to the .exe file when running the bundle.

Comment: Yes, but it requires external file to be placed next to setup.exe. In my case, I have setup.exe 1.5GB and external.msi around 1GB. The installation fails. when I forget to place external.msi next to setup.exe.

Comment: I suppose you could download it from the Internet directly instead? I haven't tested all of that. It depends how big the external setup is I guess.

Comment: I guess external.msi can be downloaded from the Internet, but in my case, I have to do it offline and this solution is just fine.