# How to silent install an UWP appx?

Tags: uwp, installation, silent-installer, appx

I develop an UWP appx, It could be installed in a cmd.exe prompt:
C:\test>myapp.appx
but a windows  GUI pop up during installtion.
Is there any method
to install it with a Silent parameter like as:
C:\test>myapp.appx /silent   (or /s)
in order to inhibit the GUI from pop up ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft provides PowerShell cmdlets for controlling AppX and MSIX packages. The command you need is [Add-AppxPackage](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh856048.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

**[EDIT]** Here is an updated list with all the [PS commandlets](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/msix-powershell-cmdlets.html) useful for managing MSIX/APPX packages.

```
PS C:\> Add-AppxPackage -Path C:\Users\user1\Desktop\MyApp.appx
```

Comment: the similar way by powershell to removepackage silently PS : Get-AppxPackage myAppID | Remove-AppxPackage