# Is it possible to install an .appxbundle (UWP/XAML app) without admin rights?

Tags: windows, powershell, uwp, software-distribution, appx

I've been working with UWP/Xaml for the past couple days but am unable to answer the title question so far: Is it possible to install an .appxbundle without admin rights?

I'm developing a Unity3D/UWP/Xaml application which cant be deployed to Windows Store and thus needs to be sideloaded and am also using the default Visual Studio 2017 test certificate. Both developer and client PCs are running on Windows 10 x64 with latest build. Developer PC is in Developer Mode and Client PC is in Sideload Apps Mode.

The project generated have the following dependencies:

1. Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.1.appx
2. Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.14.00.appx

Using powershell scripts shouldnt be a problem as long as they dont need admin rights.

I've tried a few things with no success so far:

- Double clicking the .appxbundle

  - Results in the following message: A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root certificate which isn't trusted (0x800B0109)
- Double clicking the certificate generated by visual studio and installing it to CURRENT USER (Local Machine requires admin rights), then placing certificate to either Trusted Root Certification Authorities or Trusted People and clicking again on .appxbundle
- Running the powershell script

  - Returns the following message: Before installing this app you need to do the following: Acquire a developer license
  - Then it asks for admin rights
- Running the powershell script after modifying the CheckIfNeedDeveloperLicense to always return $false

  - Returns the following message: error 0x800B0109: The root certificate of the signature in the app package or bundle must be trusted.
  - Somehow I have a feeling that the dependency Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.14.00.appx is triggering this. Also, I cant manually install this .appx because it gives me the following message: App installation failed with error message: The package could not be installed because resources it modifies are currently in use. (0x80073d02)
- Tried a mix of powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy commands before running the visual studio generated powershell script, including:

  - Force
  - ByPass
  - AllSigned
  - Unrestricted
  - -Scope CurrentUser
- Deploy visual studio project (which generates an .appx instead of an .appxbundle) instead of Store -> Create App Package

I have also read this thread [UWP App Installation without admin rights, powershell interaction and without Windows Store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50331879/uwp-app-installation-without-admin-rights-powershell-interaction-and-without-wi)
But I couldnt figure out how to configure the powershell script to run without admin rights.

Everything points me to a faulty certificate, but I still don't get how to generate a trusted one for sideloading apps. Is it possible to do it for free?

Let me know if any more info is needed in order to solve this.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to install an .appxbundle without admin rights

You must have administrative access successfully before you install. The issue you met is one of the most frequent issues when sideloading an application for first time in the user machine: *Trusted certificates*.

According to Trusted certificates section of the document [Troubleshoot installation issues with the App Installer file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/troubleshoot-appinstaller-issues):

> To trust the certificate, the certificate must be present in one of the following local machine certificate stores on your device:  Trusted Publishers,Trusted People,Trusted Root Authorities (not recommended)

No matter which one, Installing a certificate in the Local Machine store requires **administrative access**. Please kindly check the *Important* section.