# Is it possible to get GUID of application from InstallShiel 2009 install package without installing application?

Tags: windows-installer, installation, installshield, guid

I have some file, like `setup.exe` which contains application's single file installer created with InstallShield 2009. Is there a way to extract application's GUID without actual installing of the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was managed to get GUID for InstallShield's single file installer.
Here are the steps:

1. Unpack it with `isunpack.exe` utility (source: http://www.compdigitec.com/labs/files/isxunpack.exe):

   Syntax: `C:\> isunpack.exe  setup.exe`
2. It creates a `Disk1` folder with unpacked installer.
3. Open `setup.ini` and read `ProductGUID` property:

   ```
   [Startup]
   AppName=MY_PRODUCT
   ProductGUID=ca96f3a1-f350-11d3-b354-002035c150e5
   ...
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Extract the setup first using `setup.exe /a`. Answer dialogs as appropriately, you will need to set an extract location. Check this answer for more details on extracting your **setup.exe**: **[Extract MSI from EXE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547809/extract-msi-from-exe/24987512#24987512)**

When the extract is done, locate and open the MSI file and check for the **Upgrade code** and the **Product code**s in the **Property table**. You need **Installshield**, **Orca** or any other tool capable of opening the MSI file.

The package code you can find by right clicking the MSI file itself and selecting Properties.

---

Some links:

- [**setup.exe pdf reference sheet**](http://www.itninja.com/static/090770319967727eb89b428d77dcac07.pdf)
- [**Setup.exe and Update.exe Command-Line Parameters**](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield20helplib/Content/helplibrary/IHelpSetup_EXECmdLine.htm)
- **[Uninstalling an MSI file from the command line without using msiexec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450027/uninstalling-an-msi-file-from-the-command-line-without-using-msiexec/1055933#1055933)**
- **[How can I find the product GUID of an installed MSI setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937568/how-can-i-find-the-product-guid-of-an-installed-msi-setup/29937569)**

---

Comment: Sorry, but this answer is not relevant. I was asking about InstallShield 2009, not MSI.