# How to extract files (drivers) from .msi with .mst (transform) created by Advanced Installer?

Tags: windows, windows-installer, installation, extract, drivers

I'm trying to extract Fresco Logic USB3.0 Host Driver ( https://support.frescologic.com/portal/home ) from installer.

This is how it looks after extraction.
[image]

I've downloaded Advanced Installer but I do not see any option regarding file export. (drag and drop function does not work either)

[image]

Does anybody know how to get those files? My goal is to slipstream them into windows 7 image via DISM.

Answer (score 1):

Did you just run the exe file directly? You should be able to extract like this from a command prompt:

- `FLUSB3.0-3.8.33709.0.exe /extract`

Make sure the folder you are in is writeable for you, and you should get an output folder `6187973` with all the files you refer to (the actual driver files). Not sure which ones you need.

---

Tip: This site is for programmers, the site dedicated to system administration is [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com). And there is [superuser.com](http://superuser.com) for advanced users.

---

As you know, you can also use these MSI packages to deploy the drivers to a machine that has been set up based on your base Windows image. I guess this could be better if newer drivers are likely to be provided down the line?

---

Some links for safekeeping:

- [Add and Remove Drivers to an offline Windows Image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/add-and-remove-drivers-to-an-offline-windows-image).
- [DPInst.exe](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/svengruenitz/2008/07/02/driver-installation-and-updating-made-easy-dpinst-exe/) (tool from [DIFx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ff544838(v=vs.80))).
- [Extract MSI from EXE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547809/extract-msi-from-exe/24987512#24987512).

Comment: Thank you!  /extract switch works like a charm!

Comment: Great, maybe also mark the answer as accepted? (stats thing for you as well). For the record: you can extract files from MSI files like that by running this command line:  `msiexec.exe /a FLUSB3.0.msi TRANSFORMS=FLUSB3.0.mst` and then specifying a path in the setup dialog that shows up where the extracted files will go. This is [a generic extraction mechanism for all, standard MSI files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547809/extract-msi-from-exe/24987512#24987512).