# Running Wix bundle installer fails during installation

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installaware

I have created an installation bundle using Wix3.5. Within a Bundle I created a Chain element to install prerequisites (VC Runtime and another inhouse application's installer) before installing the main application. The other inhouse application's installer was created with Installaware. Now the main installation fails after the Installaware installer finishes with this error message in the installer window:

`0x80070064 - Cannot create another system semaphore`

Excerpt from the installer log:

`[2750:1D60][2019-02-28T16:08:58]e000: Error 0x80070064: Process returned error: 0x64
[2750:1D60][2019-02-28T16:08:58]e000: Error 0x80070064: Failed to configure per-user EXE package.
[2750:1D60][2019-02-28T16:08:58]i319: Applied execute package: CEInstaller, result: 0x80070064, restart: None
[2750:1D60][2019-02-28T16:08:58]e000: Error 0x80070064: Failed to execute EXE package.`

However, it seems that the bundled application is installed correctly and can be run as well.
After trying to bundle some other installers instead for testing, it seems that this error only occurs with our Installaware inhouse applications but not with other third party installers. I went through the corresponding Installaware logs but did not find anything suspicious (As these are huge I refrained from posting them here for now).
I am pretty much stuck with this issue (also I am quite new working with Windows installer frameworks). Searching online did not deliver any helpful results so far, so I am grateful for any hints how to solve or further investigate this issue.

Comment: I don't know much about Installaware I am afraid. Maybe some checks: How many Installaware setups? There are several right? Have you tested them each on their own installed via a batch file that checks the errorlevel they each set or errors they report? Just to verify what they actually report back. Maybe use C# instead (Process & ProcessStartInfo) to check?

Comment: It turned out that the Installaware installers were running sub-installers themselves which caused the problem.

Comment: Are you able to extract them and run them separately? Are they MSI installers? I hear InstallAware `setup.exe` files might be possible to extract using 7-zip? I don't really know, I don't use InstallAware. [General setup.exe extraction advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24987512/129130).

Comment: Sorry, I missed the point that these InstallAware installers are your own installers. That settles it then? How did you discover the sub-installer? Via batch?

Comment: No, I was already aware that there are sub-installers in the Installaware installers, but not that these cause the problem. And thanks for the link, that was quite informative.