# Can I silently install a setup.exe or msi files when setup gui asks for credentials and updates existing ones?

Tags: windows-installer, installation, silent-installer

I've a software which consists of six `msi files`, a `setup.exe` and `vcredist.exe` and I want to install it silently. A silent installation of the `msi files` is not possible but I can use `myprogram.msi /passive`. But here I've three problems.

1. An existing version of the program is already installed and the silent installation doesn't update the existing one it justs installs it in addition to the old one.
2. In the dialogs of `setup.exe` it asks for credentials for a service which will be installed/ updated. But while installing the msi I don't know how to pass the credentials?
3. There are other user interactions while running `setup.exe` like if setup should configure firewall.

The functionality of the `setup.exe` is also just a wrapper around those `msi files`, isn't it? Question is, is there a way to accomplish installing those `msi files` silently with supplying the user interaction like the `setup.exe` does?

Comment: In corporations whole teams exist to take care of deployments like this - it can be very fiddly and complicated. Perhaps you are in a company with an existing team to package applications and adapt installation programs? Might be worth a check. Short, keyword answers: `1)` Major upgrade is not working - fix Upgrade table, `2)` All depends what tool was used to create that [`setup.exe`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24987512/129130) in order to know how to approach it, `3)` You might want to do that via other means than software packages? Active Directory?

Comment: [Major Upgrade vs. Minor Upgrade vs. Small Update](https://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield24helplib/helplibrary/MajorMinorSmall.htm). [How To: Implement a Major Upgrade In Your Installer](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/updates/major_upgrade.html) (WiX). WiX has means to configure firewalls via the MSI package. Not rocket science, not trivial either. [FirewallException](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/firewall/firewallexception.html).

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit of spaghetti in your question, let's highlight a bit:

- Silent installation of MSI is possible, it is `/quiet` switch, not `/passive`. The successful silent installation depends on a package (whether it is per-machine or per-user) and given rights elevation (whether they're elevated or not)
- If silent installation does not update the existing one but installs in addition — means problem with your ProductCode/UpgradeCode values
- You can't pass ask for credentials if they are required, that's what they were designed for, I mean we're talking about UAC, right?
- setup.exe is also just a wrapper around those msi files, isn't it — may be, may be not. Since it is an .exe, it can do a lot of stuff

Consider revising the design of your deployment solution