# Old InstallShield installer won't proceed due to ".NET Framework v. 2.0.50727 or later is not installed"

Tags: windows, windows-installer, installshield

I'm trying to get an old program to install on Windows Server 2019.

I enabled ".NET Framework 3.5 Features" -> ".NET Framework 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0)" via Server Manager but the installer fails to proceed after displaying the following dialog:

"Unable to install ..., since .NET Framework v 2.0.50727 or later is not installed on this computer. ... requires .NET Framework.

What do I need to do to enable this installer to proceed?

Comment: Use an MSI editor such as [Orca](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48482546/129130) (see link for other tools too) and open the MSI in question. Look for entries in the LaunchCondition table that are incorrect. You are supposed to modify an MSI using a transform (external file used to modify the MSI content on load) to prevent editing the MSI directly, but you can make a copy of the MSI to test first and just delete entries from that table. There could also be custom actions preventing the installation, but try the LaunchCondition cleanup first.

Comment: Is this an MSI or a setup.exe? [Setup.exe extraction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24987512/129130).

Comment: @SteinÅsmul it's an .exe. When I run setup.exe, it opens the usual setup dialog. But when I run setup.exe /s, it opens Install.exe which is the subsequent part that checks for .NET Framework. I should add it's from 2013.

Comment: What software suite is this? Please look for it in the ITNINJA Software Library and see if there are any "packaging tips" available for the package. Do a search for it on this page: https://www.itninja.com/software-library/software