# UAC promts "Unknown Publisher" on uninstall only

Tags: windows-installer, uac, uninstallation, publisher

I have signed my MSI installer with a valid certificate.
When I install this MSI the UAC prompts and display the Publisher name properly.
However, when I uninstall the MSI UAC prompts saying "Unknown Publisher".

If checked in the `C:\Windows\Installer` folder for the cached installer and it doesn't have the certificate!

So why doesn't it keep the certificate for the cached installer?

Answer (score 1):

If you're running on Windows Vista (or Windows Server 2008) this is a [well-known behavior of Windows Installer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2009/02/02/changes-to-package-caching-in-windows-installer-5-0.aspx) <sup>[archive](https://archive.ph/thlm6)</sup>.

> Windows Installer strips-out embedded cabinets to save space. Unfortunately, altering the `.msi` in this way also invalidates the digital signature.

You can avoid this by building your `.msi` without embedded cabs; that is have all the files you install be outside the `.msi` itself. If you're seeing this on Windows 7 or later, however, that would be unexpected.

Comment: [Here is a whole messy answer on MSI caching behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1189524/129130) and how it has changed between OS versions.