# Including MSI files in my own installer: Where to put the MSI?

Tags: windows-installer, nsis

I'm developing an installer (written in NSIS script) and I'd like to include a third party MSI file that is a prerequisite for my application.

It's quite easy to install an MSI file using `msiexec.exe /i somelibrary.msi`, but this only works correctly the first time. I found out that this has something to do with the source location that Windows Installer saves in the registry.

I read some posts about the MSI source location like this one:

[Why does MSI require the original .msi file to proceed with an uninstall?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208530/why-does-msi-require-the-original-msi-file-to-proceed-with-an-uninstall)

The question is: **Where do I put the original `SomeLibrary.msi` file so that it is preserved for future repair or reinstall operations?**

If I put the file in my applications target location (e.g. in `C:\Program Files\...`) it will be removed with my application uninstaller.

A reinstallation attempt in another directory then results in `A network error occurred while attempting to read from the file C:\Program Files\...\SomeLibrary.msi` which is understandable since the original source MSI file has been removed in the uninstallation process.

I understand that Windows Installer creates a cached version of the MSI, but that is stripped of all files so that only a simple uninstall is still possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recent versions of Windows / Windows Instaler ( Win7 / 8 I think )  don't strip the MSI anymore to preserve the authenticode signing.  Also not all installers require their MSI to uninstall.  Typically badly authored ones that use the ResolveSource action incorrectly do.

The main thing is to put the MSI in a location that a non-priv user can read it but cannot modify it.  [CommonAppDataFolder]\Downloaded Installation\Company\Product\Rev is typically a good place where Rev is a PackageCode guid.