# Why does installation of an update.exe need the orginal .msi file?

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

The Scenario:
I made an update for my product and I used InstallSheild to create it.

- When testing the update it popped up a dialog saying "The feature you are trying to use is on a network resource that is unavailable".
- It had a box named "Use source:", which had the path that the original install was run from.
- It was run from a directory on the network that had been renamed.
- I was able to put the new directory name in the box and the update completed - I used the "Browse..." button to enter the directory name, and it had the name of the msi file shown, so when I entered the path, it got the path to the msi file.

My Question/Problem:

- Why did running the Update.exe need the path to the original msi file to finish running?
- I don't want an end user to need that.
- I have't seen an Update.exe need an msi file before.
- I ask this question so that I can figure out what I can do to prevent an Update.exe from needing the original msi file?

Comment: [Some details here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1189524/129130).

Comment: @SteinÅsmul That link has some really good information.  I would mark it as the answer, but I cannot do that for a comment.

Comment: Which part helped? You can give it an upvote if you like. I can perhaps write a short answer here quickly (for others with similar problems). It is hard to know with Installshield and **`update.exe`** and **`setup.exe`** issues - and I am not set up to test properly as of now.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul I don't think I can say concisely.  There is a long post there describing how it uses the original msi file.

Comment: This other post answered my question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208530/why-does-msi-require-the-original-msi-file-to-proceed-with-an-uninstall/1189524#1189524